# can I reverse engineer database to jdl file?

Tags: jhipster

I have created schema diagram in mysql workbench.  Is it possible to convert sql file into jdl?  Or reverse engineer database schema into jdl file?

Comment: It won't do all the job but i can help you, try this module: https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper

Comment: Thanks, Pascal.  Will try this module

Comment: I just now searched for a reverse engineering approach for JHipster and an existing MySQL database and found this thread - but then I noted that the proposed solution of using jhipster-db-helper

- No longer appears to be maintained/updated (last update was June 2020)

- It doesn't appear to be working with a recent JHipster version (as per https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper/issues/82)

So I think i'll look for an alternative option.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `jhipster-db-helper`

e.g.

`npm install -g generator-jhipster-db-helper`

then

`yo jhipster-db-helper`

then update if requried
  .jhipster/yourtables.json

Comment: I just now searched for a reverse engineering approach for JHipster and an existing MySQL database and found this thread - but then I noted that the proposed solution of using jhipster-db-helper

- No longer appears to be maintained/updated (last update was June 2020)

- It doesn't appear to be working with a recent JHipster version (as per https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper/issues/82)

So I think i'll look for an alternative option.